# Read Data from MongoDB through Apache Spark with a query

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am able to read the data stored in MongoDB via Apache Spark via the conventional methods described in its documentation. I have a mongoDB query that I would like to be used while loading the collection. The query is simple, but I can't seem to find the correct way to specify the query the `config()` function in SparkSession object.

Following is my SparkSession builder

```
val confMap: Map[String, String] = Map(
      "spark.mongodb.input.uri" -> "mongodb://xxx:xxx@mongodb1:27017,mongodb2:27017,mongodb3:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=MongoShard-0&authSource=xxx&retryWrites=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1",
      "spark.mongodb.input.database" -> "A",
      "spark.mongodb.input.collection" -> "people",
      "spark.mongodb.output.database" -> "B",
      "spark.mongodb.output.collection" -> "result",
      "spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name" -> "primaryPreferred"
    )
    conf.setAll(confMap)
    val spark: SparkSession =
      SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").config(conf).getOrCreate()
```

Is there a way to specify the MongoDB query in the SparkConf object so that the SparkSession reads only the specific fields present in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.withPipeline` API

**Example Code:**

```
val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> MONGO_DEV_URI, "collection" -> MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME, "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred"))

    MongoSpark
    .load(spark.sparkContext, readConfig)
    .withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse(query)))
```

As per comments:

```
sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
.option("pipeline", "[{ $match: { name: { $exists: true } } }]")
.option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.mycoll")
.load()
```

Comment: I do not wish to use the RDD APIs. Is there a way to do it via the SparkSession? Is there a way I can specify the aggregation pipeline as a configuration parameter?

Comment: I have used the same but getting Exception.Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294454/getting-exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-in-spark-streaming-scala-mo